# Want wp_get_post_terms return in arbitrarily order, how to do?

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, terms

Function below returns in alphabetical order and not, as wished, in arbitrarily order.
Is it possible to -not- return in alphabetical but in exact order as given in the array?

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_function');
function my_function($content) {
if ( is_single() && in_category( '5' ) ) {
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'top-post-img' ));    

global $post;
$term_list=wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,array('school','article','teacher'),array( "fields" => "names"));
?>
<div style="margin:45px;">
    School: <strong><?php print_r($term_list[0]); ?></strong><br />
    Article: <strong><?php print_r($term_list[1]); ?></strong><br />
    Teacher: <strong><?php print_r($term_list[2]); ?></strong>
</div>
<?php       
return $content;
} else { 
return $content;
}
}
```

I tried by adding:

```
array ('orderby' => 'post__in'),  array ('post__in' => '24', '10', '3', '46' )
```

Numbers are the Taxonomy ID's but it is not changing any, neither does it throw an error.

To find the Taxonomy ID's I used following code, or is that the wrong code?

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'taxonomy-name' );
if($terms) {
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->term_id.'<br />';
}
}
```

Should I use `list_filter` somewhere, or some below in the code after the  `print_r` ?

Added

```
 var_dump($term_list);
```

to see if output would show some else, but no it was the same..alphabetical order.
I am pretty sure forgetting some but what, and where. Or is my approach totally wrong?

Would love to find a solution.
Thanks in advance for all time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('the_content','my_function');
function my_function($content){
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'top-post-img' ));

  if (is_single() && in_category('5')){
    global $post;
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms ($post->ID,'school',array('fields'=>'names'));
    ?>
    <div id="some_class">
    <span>School:<strong><?php print_r($term_list[0]); ?></strong></span>
    <?php
    if (is_single() && in_category('5')){
        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms ($post->ID,'article',array('fields' =>'names'));
        ?>
        <span>Article:<strong><?php print_r($term_list[0]); ?></strong></span>
        <?php
        if (is_single() && in_category('5')){
            $term_list = wp_get_post_terms ($post->ID,'teacher',array('fields'=>'names'));
            ?>
            <span>Teacher:<strong><?php print_r($term_list[0]); ?></strong></span>
            </div>
            <?php
            return $content;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

[image: Output as shown in Post]

Thanks to suggestions made by **Rarst**, this code works like a charm.
As you can see, it does show the `Featured Image` which belongs to that post,
and the output is returned in exact order as wished in the code.
It also uses some CSS to style (in the style.css) so it shows nice below
the title and above the content.

**Update**
Getting Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Anyone around to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at source for [`wp_get_object_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_object_terms/) which a lot of related functions use internally, there is not option for custom `orderby` in it. I would probably just re-sort returned data in PHP for this.

However even more practically I would just retrieve terms for different taxonomies separately. What you have there looks tad fragile logically - for example what if one of terms is missing, or there are more than expected assigned by mistake? Output will go bad fast.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst for your reply, I changed the code as shown above, it does not drop any error and the returns are as wished. Reading your comment, I don't understand what you mean by: _I would probably just re-sort returned data in PHP for this._ Pleas could you enlighten me? If the re-coding I show is totally off, please tell.
About the issue empty term and/or more than one assigned: using code here so only radio buttons (1 option only) and missing term (if selected none for example), authors will do input but cannot publish, editor will do the checks and will published after approve.

Comment: @Charles I meant the data returned by function is not chiseled in stone. :) You can always modify it with PHP code, such as changing order of items in array. But as per answer I think retrieving terms separately makes more sense to me, your update seems sound.